# error code #1452 when adding foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql

Error

SQL query:

```
ALTER TABLE `bids` ADD  FOREIGN KEY (`buyerID`) REFERENCES `e_trading_post`.`buyer`(`buyerID`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

MySQL said:

> > 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('e_trading_post' .'#sql-15d48_6a8', CONSTRAINT `#sql-15d48_6a8_ibfk_1' FOREIGN KEY ('buyerID') REFERENCES 'buyer;  ('buyerID') ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: no that answer just gave me more error

under say bids table in mamp when i click on relationship view and it list the primary key and foreign keys with the drop down to link the FK to their original table where they are a primary key i get this error and there technically is no reason for it as i could link them in on one table but no others...i need to link all the tables in relationship view

Answer (score 1):

This error means that this specific foreign key constraint cannot be created as it would be violated (is is violated right now).

The following query might help you to find the violating row:

```
select buyerID from bids where buyerID not in (select buyer from e_trading_post)
```

Comment: Hi @helene-bourke if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.